# Kendo grid getKendoGrid not working with extended kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement Kendo Grid "SelectAll" feature for our extended Kendo grid. When "SelectAll" Column included, UI is rendering properly But, the "Select All" header checkbox click is not working. Noticed that **getKendoGrid** method is not working with extended Kendo grid.

**Kendo.web.js....**

```
_headerCheckboxClick: function (e) {
   var  that = this, 
        checkBox = $(e.target), 
        checked = checkBox.prop('checked'), 
        **parentGrid = checkBox.closest('.k-grid.k-widget').getKendoGrid();**
   if (that !== parentGrid) {
       return;
   }
   if (checked) {
       that.select(parentGrid.items());
   } else {
       that.clearSelection();
   }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use checkBox.closest('.k-grid.k-widget').data("kendoGrid") instead of getKendo* method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's the Kendo.web.js plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

that function change is name to the parameter `d`

```
o = <your_kendo_plugin_name>
d = "kendo" + o
```

so you should use the function `kendoGrid()` instead of `getKendoGrid()`,